# Redirect subirectories without affecting the main directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

While updating things in WordPress I found that plugins that generate slugs can't use a slug that's already in use by another page so I have had to change the slug to be something slightly different. I now need to make sure that anyone that tries the old urls get redirected to the new one without affecting the main page.

So I have `/members/` with a list of members and you can click members to go to `/member/[name]` I need to redirect `/members/[name]` to the `/member/[name]`
( *[name] can be anything so it needs to be a wildcard.*)

I have used both of the following htaccess rules (not at the same time) but they always end up redirecting the /members/ page also which breaks everything.

```
RewriteRule ^members/(.*) http://domain.tld/member [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/members/.*$ http://domain.tld/member
```

What am I missing to make it only redirect if there's something after the `/`

*Sidenote: I've tried finding an answer to this but all the results I have found are trying to do the exact opposite (redirecting only the exact match of /members/) that I need and wont work.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the captured part of the request.

Try :

```
RedirectMatch ^/members/(.+)$ /member/$1
```

Comment: oh, that's not good, okay i fixed that but /members... nevermind your update fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /oldDir/old.php http://yourDomain/newDir/new.php
```

Comment: This doesn't look like what i'm trying to accomplish? what exactly is going on here `^(.*)$ http://%1/$1` ?

Comment: I do not know the details. I just know it works for me.

Comment: Oh I think you misunderstand, I would like to redirect a wildcard of sub-directories like /members/1 /members/2 etc..  

Also I think i understand your `http://%1/$1` it seems to be using a wildcard for "www" in case it's not there i believe.

Comment: This page explains the regular expressions for htaccess files https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite. You can replace a part of the URL, check this example where "%F3" is replaced with "?"

Comment: Try this to change the name of the directory RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /oldDir/
RewriteRule ^services/(.*)$ /newDir/$1 [L]

Comment: The rewrite docs are so confusing I tried to give them a read and was trying to get it but Starkeen's answer does exactly what i needed in a much smaller bit of code (the key being the `+` and well.. catching the rest of the request)